# HTML файл не реагирует на содержание CSS файла в Angular 7

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, angular

содержание css файла:

```
 h1 { 

color: #336; /* Цвет текста */
font-size: 120%; /* Размер шрифта */
}
```

содержание html файла:

```
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<!-- <ul> -->
<div style="text-align:center">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<div class="row">
 <div>
  <h1 >
    Welcome to {{ title }}
  </h1>
 </div>
```

src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyNTAgMjUwIj4KICAgIDxwYXRoIGZpbGw9IiNERDAwMzEiIGQ9Ik0xMjUgMzBMMzEuOSA2My4ybDE0LjIgMTIzLjFMMTI1IDIzMGw3OC45LTQzLjcgMTQuMi0xMjMuMXoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjQzMwMDJGIiBkPSJNMTI1IDMwdjIyLjItLjFWMjMwbDc4LjktNDMuNyAxNC4yLTEyMy4xTDEyNSAzMHoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCAgZmlsbD0iI0ZGRkZGRiIgZD0iTTEyNSA1Mi4xTDY2LjggMTgyLjZoMjEuN2wxMS43LTI5LjJoNDkuNGwxMS43IDI5LjJIMTgzTDEyNSA1Mi4xem0xNyA4My4z aC0zNGwxNy00MC45IDE3IDQwLjl6IiAvPgogIDwvc3ZnPg==">
   
   -->

```
 <ul>
   <button style="background-color:rgb(177, 19, 19); font-size: 10rem;" 
    >click 
  on me</button>
     <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://mbou- 
    sosh18.edu95.ru/">Сош №18 </a></h2>

  <li>
     <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://angular.io/cli">CLI 
  Documentation</a></h2>
   </li>
  <li>
  <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" 
  href="https://blog.angular.io/">Angular blog</a></h2>
   </li>
   </ul>


   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Проблема в том, что html не реагирует на содержание css файла, то есть не распознает его 
Пишу в Visual Studio Code

Comment: эм, ниче непонятно, что это за css файл, как/куда он подключается и зачем вы вставили сюда этот html?

Comment: Текст h1 Должен был измениться(цвет и размер), но эти изменения не происходят @overthesanity

Comment: вопрос был не о том что h1 должен измениться

Comment: @overthesanity можно тогда я задам вопрос немного по другому, как подключить css файл к html, если "традиционный" способ с <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/имя файла.css"> не работает